# select an item of my scope by variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my controller and it receives a parameter called let's say *time*, I'd like to refer to a ng-model in my scope based on that parameter.

**What I have:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
  $scope.minutes = 1;
}
```

**What I want:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function(time){
  $scope.time = 1;
}
```

Where *time* is the parameter received and has the value *minutes*.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the variable name as a parameter:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(propName) {
  $scope[propName] = 1;
};
```

Comment: Yes.  I think that is what the OP is after. :)